# Faithful action on trees ensures that the action is faithfull of plane graphs?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, graph-theory, group-actions, planar-graphs

Let us consider a group $G$ acting on a finite plane bipartite graph. Assume that $G$ acts faithfully on the family of finite plane trees. Does this hypothesis suffice to show that $G$ acts faithfully on the family of finite plane bipartite graphs? If yes, this is because we can restrict our attention to spanning trees?